# C# ValidationConstraints Form

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, input, constraints

I'm facing a big problem with Validation Constraints
I have a authentication form with two inputs (txtLogin, txtPasswd) and I've put constraints in order to fit the database scheme. 
I also have 3 buttons.

- One for login : btnConnect
- One for create account : btnCreateUser
- One for testing it does a simple MessageBox.show();

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MoneyManager.View
{
    public partial class LoginView : Form
    {
        public LoginView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new CreateUserView().Show();
        }

        private void txtLogin_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string pattern = @"^.*\S$";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

            if (!regex.IsMatch(txtLogin.Text.Trim()))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.loginError.SetError(txtLogin, "Le login ne peut pas être vide");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                this.loginError.SetError(txtLogin, "");
            }
        }

        private void txtPasswd_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string pattern = @"^[^.*$]\S{6,}$";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

            if (!regex.IsMatch(txtPasswd.Text.Trim()))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.passwdError.SetError(txtPasswd, "Le mot de passe ne peut pas être vide et faire min 6 caractères");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                this.passwdError.SetError(txtPasswd, "");
            }            
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Votre login : " + txtLogin.Text + " Votre mot de passe : " + txtPasswd.Text);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I click on the "button1" for example, it doesn't allow me to do that. I have to fill input before clicking on it.

So why is it happening

I've tried to comment this part :

```
if(ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Votre login : " + txtLogin.Text + " Votre mot de passe : " + txtPasswd.Text);
                }
```

In order to remove the "if" but it seems that the "if" has no effect both if it's present or not the behavior is the same !

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: This is because you have code in `txtPasswd_Validating`. If you want to click free and everywhere, don't use `control.validating` event. Validate controls "manually" when button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The method signatures are correct in your code, so I'm guessing you have not wired up the event handlers on the GUI for your buttons - or you have them wired up wrong.

Follow the arrows:

[image: screenshot]